# Gezel in Rabbinical regulations

Tags: gezel-stealing, derabanan

In the Laws of Shabbos there are multiple layers of Rabbinical prohibitions built one on top of others to prevent possible transgression of Shabbos, for example, Muktze, or playing musical instruments, or using electricity etc.

I'm looking for similar Rabbinical prohibitions or precautions to prevent possible transgression of various forms of Gezel - fraud, using a Pikadon, Ona'a, regular Gezel, Mekach Tous, using property without permission, withholding payment from a worker etc.

What Halachic Rabbinical regulations were ruled on this subject?

See for details my previous question "[how-to-beware-of-the-prohibition-of-onaa"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99049/how-to-beware-of-the-prohibition-of-onaa)

Comment: I tell my students that there are no usual Rabbinical fences on laws between man and his fellow man. This is because the way we treat people is either right or wrong. If a person is not right with how they interact with people, no amount of fences will help anyway. They will all break. :)

Comment: @DavidKenner Wait, but why? In our civil life, we have lots of governmental regulations about different aspects of trade and contracts and everything. Why do gentiles care more about בין אדם לחבירו than us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many rabbinic enactments/prohibitions related to monetary matters. Here is a sampling from the Rambam (translations from [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm)):

Gezelah 6:7

> דברים הרבה אסרו חכמים משום גזל; והעובר עליהן, הרי זה גזלן מדבריהם:  כגון מפריחי יונים והמשחקין בקוביה
>   Our Sages forbade many acts, classifying them as robbery - e.g., one who sets doves into flight or plays dice.

6:12

> מצודות חיה ועופות ודגים, שנפלו מיני החיה לתוך המצודה, ובא אחר ונטלן--הרי זה גזל מדבריהם, מפני שעדיין לא הגיעו ליד הזוכה בהן.‏
>   The following principle applies with regard to snares for beasts, fowl and fish: If an animal falls into such a snare and another person takes it, this is considered robbery by Rabbinic law. It is not considered to be robbery by Scriptural law because they have not as yet entered the possession of the person who acquires them.

6:13

> עני המנקף בראש הזית זיתים של שכחה, ובא עני אחר ונטלן מעל הארץ--הרי זה גזל מדבריהם, מפני שעדיין לא הגיעו ליד הזוכה בהן.‏
>   When a poor person climbs to the top of an olive tree and beats the branches so that olives that have been forgotten by their owner will fall, he is entitled to them. If another poor person takes them, it is considered robbery by Rabbinic decree.

6:14

> הדבורים אינן ברשותו של אדם כמו תרנגולים ואווזים, ואף על פי כן יש בהן קניין מדבריהם; והגוזל נחיל דבורים, או שמנעו מבעליו אם בא לרשותו--הרי זה גזל מדבריהם.‏
>   A person who steals a swarm of bees or prevents their owner from taking them if the swarm comes into his domain is considered a robber by Rabbinic decree.

Geneva 1:2

> ואסור לגנוב דרך שחוק, או לגנוב על מנת להחזיר, או לגנוב על מנת לשלם:  הכול אסור, שלא ירגיל עצמו בכך.‏
>   It is forbidden to steal as a jest, to steal with the intent to return, or to steal with the intent to pay. All is forbidden, lest one habituate oneself to such conduct.

5:1

> אסור לקנות מן הגנב החפץ שגנב, ועוון גדול הוא:  שהרי מחזיק ידי עוברי עבירה, וגורם לו לגנוב גניבות אחרות, שאם לא ימצא לוקח, אינו גונב; ועל זה נאמר "חולק עם גנב, שונא נפשו"‏
>   It is forbidden to buy a stolen article from a thief. This is a severe sin, for it reinforces a transgressor and motivates him to steal in the future. For if he did not find a person who would purchase a stolen article from him, he would not steal. With reference to this, Proverbs 29:24 states: "A person who shares profits with a thief hates his own soul."

7:4

> כיוצא בזה סלע שנפגמה מן הצד--לא יעשנה משקל בין משקלותיו, ולא יזרקנה בין גרוטותיו, ולא ייקבנה ויתלנה בצוואר בנו:  שמא יבוא אחר ויעשנה משקל.  אלא או ישחוק או יחתוך או יקוץ, או ישליך לים המלח.‏
>   Similarly, when a sela became blemished at its side, a person should not use it as a weight, nor should he cast it among his pieces of scrap metal, nor should he drill a hole in it and hang it around his son's neck, lest another person come and make it appear as a weight. Instead, one should grind it into powder, cut it into small pieces, pulverize it, or throw it into the Dead Sea.

7:7

> עושה אדם מידותיו סאה, וחצי סאה, ורביע סאה, וקב, וחצי קב, ורובע הקב, וחצי הרובע, ושמין הרובע; אבל לא יעשה קביים, שלא תתחלף ברובע הסאה שהוא קב ומחצה.‏
>   A person should make his measures the size of a se'ah, half a se'ah and a quarter of a se'ah, a kav, half a kav, a quarter of a kav, an eighth of a kav and a twenty-fourth of a kav. He should not, however, make a measure of two kabbim], lest it be mistaken for a quarter of a se'ah, which is a kav and a half.

Nachalot 6:10

> והגר אינו יורש את אביו הגוי, אלא מדבריהם; תיקנו לו שיירש כשהיה, שמא יחזור למרדו.‏
>   A convert does not inherit the estate of his father, a gentile. Nevertheless, our Sages ordained that he be able to inherit the estate as he was entitled previously, lest he return to rebellion against God.

6:13

> ציוו חכמים שלא ישנה אדם בן בין הבנים בחייו, אפילו בדבר מועט, שלא יבואו לידי תחרות וקנאה, כאחי יוסף עם יוסף.‏
>   Our Sages commanded that a person should not differentiate between his children in his lifetime, even with regard to a small matter, lest this spawn competition and envy as happened with Joseph and his brothers.

Nizkei Mamon 5:2

> לפיכך אסרו חכמים לגדל בהמה דקה וחיה דקה בארץ ישראל במקום השדות והכרמים, אלא ביערים ובמדברות שבארץ ישראל.‏
>   For this reason, our Sages forbade [our people] from raising small animals and small beasts in Eretz Yisrael, where there are fields and vineyards. One may, however, raise these animals in the forests and deserts of Eretz Yisrael.

5:9

> וכן אסרו חכמים לגדל חזירים בכל מקום, ולא את הכלב אלא אם כן היה קשור בשלשלת.  אבל מגדל הוא כלבים בעיר הסמוכה לספר, ביום קושרו ובלילה מתירו.  ואמרו חכמים ארור מגדל כלבים וחזירים, מפני שהיזקן מרובה ומצוי.‏
>   Similarly, our Sages forbade raising pigs in all places. Also, [our Sages forbade raising] dogs unless they are tied by a chain. One may, however, raise dogs in a city near the border. During the day [the dogs] should be chained, and at night let loose. Our Sages said: "Cursed be one who raises dogs and pigs, because they frequently cause a great degree of damage."

13:14

> לא יוציא אדם תבנו וקשו לרשות הרבים, כדי שידושו ויעשו לו זבל.  ואם הוציא, קנסו אותו חכמים שיהיו כהפקר, וכל הקודם בהן זכה, מעת שנידושו והשביחו.‏
>   A person should not take his straw and hay out to the public domain so that it will be trod upon and become fit to use as fertilizer. If he did take it out, our Sages penalized him and declared the straw to be ownerless. The first person to take possession of it acquires it as his own, once it has been trod upon and its value has increased.

Sechirut 11:5

> המשהה שכר שכיר עד אחר זמנו--אף על פי שכבר עבר בעשה ולא תעשה, הרי זה חייב ליתן מיד.  וכל עת שישהה--עובר על לאו של דבריהם, שנאמר "אל תאמר לריעך, לך ושוב" (משלי ג,כח).‏
>   When a person delays payment of a worker's wages until after they are due, he is liable to pay him immediately, although he has already violated the positive and the negative commandment mentioned above. Throughout the time he delays payment, he transgresses a Rabbinic commandment, as alluded to by Proverbs 3:28: "Do not tell your colleague, 'Go and return for tomorrow I will pay.'

Pikadon 6:1

> שומר חינם שאמר הריני משלם, ואיני נשבע--אם היה הפיקדון דבר שכל מינו שווה ומצוי בשוק לקנות כמותו כגון פירות, או יריעות של צמר או של פשתן השוות בכל עניינם, או קורות המצויות, וכל כיוצא בהן--הרי זה משלם, ואינו נשבע.  אבל אם היה הפיקדון בהמה, או בגד מצוייר, או כלי מתוקן, או דבר שאינו מוצא לקנות כמותו בשווה--חוששין שמא עיניו נתן בו, ומשביעין אותו בתקנת חכמים שבועה בנקיטת חפץ שאינו ברשותו; ואחר כך משלם.‏
>
> The following rules apply when an unpaid watchman says, "I desire to pay and not to take an oath: If the entrusted article is of a uniform type and it is possible to purchase such articles in the market-place - e.g., produce, reams of wool and flax that are entirely uniform, beams on which images have not been carved, or the like- he may pay the value of the article and be excused from taking an oath.
>
> If, however, the entrusted article was an animal, a decorated garment, a utensil that had been fixed, or an article that is not easily available to purchase in the market place, we suspect that the watchman coveted it for himself. We therefore require him to take an oath as instituted by our Sages, while holding a sacred article, that the entrusted object is no longer in his possession. Afterwards, he must make restitution.

Mechira 3:5

> ולמה תיקנו חכמים דבר זה במיטלטלין--גזירה שמא ייתן הלוקח דמי החפץ וקודם שייקחנו יאבד באונס, כגון שנפלה דליקה ונשרף, או באו ליסטים ונטלוהו:  אם יהיה ברשות הלוקח, יתמהמה המוכר ולא יצילו.  לפיכך העמידוהו חכמים ברשות המוכר, כדי שישתדל ויציל החפץ, שאם אבד, יהיה חייב לשלם.‏
>   Why did our Sages make such an ordinance with regard to movable property? This is a decree, enacted lest a purchaser pay for an article and before he takes possession of it, it be destroyed by factors beyond his control - e.g., a fire breaks out and burns it, or thieves come and take it. If the article is considered as in the possession of the purchaser, the seller may hesitate and not endeavor to save it.
>
> For this reason, our Sages ordained that the article remain within the possession of the seller, so that he will attempt to save it. For if it is destroyed, he is obligated to pay.